# I try to run flutter application but I found build.gradle error

Tags: plugins, build.gradle, google-play-services, gradle-plugin

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'E:\FINAL YEAR PROJECT\FYP final\smart_dustbin\smart_dustbin\android\build.gradle' line: 18
- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.google.gms.google-services', version: '4.3.15', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.google.gms.google-services:com.google.gms.google-services.gradle.plugin:4.3.15')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1